# could not create react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I was trying to create a react project using the command

```
npx create-react-app chat-app
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Creating a new React app in /home/mikhil/react-tutorial/internshala-react-course/chat-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. 
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!  npm ERR! Found: @babel/core@undefined 
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/core npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: 
npm ERR! peer @babel/core@"^7.0.0-0" from @babel/preset-env@7.13.10 
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/preset-env 
npm ERR!   @babel/preset-env@"^7.12.1" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@svgr/webpack 
npm ERR!     @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-scripts 
npm ERR!       react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! See /home/mikhil/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     /home/mikhil/.npm/_logs/2021-03-18T11_58_50_255Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel
error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json 
Deleting chat-app/ from /home/mikhil/react-tutorial/internshala-react-course
Done.
```

Comment: What version of Node and NPM are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to update npm with `npm update` and see if that fixes it, and if not you can try these steps.

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, it is recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

You will also want to delete your remnant files and folders for `chat-app`

Once you are in the `/home/mikhil/react-tutorial/internshala-react-course` directory and you have removed the global installations you can try running these commands.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

[Create React App - Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with NPM version 7.20.0.
Simply install an older version of NPM.
In the terminal run: `npm install npm@6.14.11 -g`

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some particular versions of NPM that cause this issue. Try updating to the very latest version of NPM.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do the same the whole day, then at last I have to open the documentation, there it was mentioned that you can also create react app using

```
npm init create-react-app **app_name**
```

and it worked for me fine.

I was troubled very much by this dependency thing.

Comment: It should be `npm init react-app`. [Also, this is just another way of doing what OP was doing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#creating-an-app), and doesn't actually answer the question.